# What is the best to add accelerometer noise to PPG signals?

Tags: deep-learning

I have a BIDMC PPG signals. I'm trying to add accelerometer data as a noise to PPG signals and trying to denoise it using deep generative models like GANs, VAEs, Diffusion Models. So, what can be the best way to add noise so that the it wouldn't distort the signal so much that we lose all the original information?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question refer to the stochastic noise sources of the sensor, and not to the deterministic ones (mis-alignement, scale-factors, non-orthogonalities, etc.)

Accelerometers tend to have three different stochastic noise sources:

- White Noise
- Flicker noise (bias instability)
- Random walk

You can find a detailed explanation of each of these stochastic noise sources in these papers [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9955423) and [[2]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S026322411730578X).

The applicability of each noise source depends of several factors but most importantly the quality of your sensor. A MEMS sensor will have bigger noise levels that a Navigation-grade sensor. Overall though, on small acquisition time (less than a few minutes for a MEMS sensor, few hours for a high-end one), the assumption of a white noise only can hold.

The noises values you can expect can be directly taken from your sensor datasheet or derived from an Allan Variance curve.

Comment: I'm taking the accelerometer signals from Polar H10 chest strap.  The average of maximum differences is taken in accelerometer data within specified windows. These averages are then used to generate a noisy version of the clean PPG signal. The noise is added to the PPG signal by scaling the average differences like in this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/full/10.1145/3563949) . But the noise added to it is in increasing order, which I don't think it as a good way. I don't know I may be wrong.

Comment: So you are using the signal of the accelerometer as a "clean signal" ?